# How Accelerate factor function from SAGE

Tags: python, sage

I'm wrote a method to get the symbolic coefficients of polynomial p \in GF(2^pp)[X0,...,X_{nvars-1}] translate to GF(2)[t]. For example for pp = 2. The polynomial p = X0*X1 = (x_00+x_01*t)*(x_10+x_11*t) = (x_00*x_10+x_01*x_11) + (x_01*x_11+x_01*x_10 + x_00*x_11)*t  then the method get [(x_00*x_10+x_01*x_11),(x_01*x_11+x_01*x_10 + x_00*x_11)]. My problem is when the number pp and nvars are high. I have taked the times and the instruction the need more time is p.factor(). Then my question is How I will be able to accelerate that code?

```
pp = 2
nvars = 2
k.<t>=GF(2^pp)
vars_GF = []
vars_gf2 = []
for i in range(nvars):
    vars_GF.append(var("X"+str(i)))
    for j in range(pp):
    vars_gf2.append(var("x"+str(i)+str(j)))
vars_GF = None        
vars_GF = ["X%d"%i for i in range(nvars)]  
R=PolynomialRing(k,names=vars_gf2)
P=PolynomialRing(k,names=vars_GF)
p=P.random_element(degree=2)
subsvar=[sum((t^i*R.gen(i+pp*j) for i in range(pp))) for j in range(nvars)]        
p = p(subsvar)
print type(p)
var("t")
timeit('SR(p)')
p = SR(p)
p = p.factor()
timeit('p.factor()')
p = p.collect(t)
timeit('p.collect(t)')
print "p",p
print p.coefficients()
```

Comment: `vars_gf2.append(var("x"+str(i)+str(j)))` will generate the same variable for i=11,j=1 as i=1,j=11.

Comment: ok @AndrewJohnson but this part is very fast in my code the problem is with factor method. because I use that many many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you only want to obtain the coefficients of powers of `t` as polynomials in the variables `x_i_j`, so it's not clear to me why you would need to factor at all.

Suggestion: work in an appropriate polynomial ring, rather than in the symbolic ring.

```
sage: q = 2
sage: nvars = 2
sage: k.<t> = GF(2^q)
sage: x_i = []
sage: x_i_j = []
sage: for i in range(nvars):
....:     x_i.append(var('x_'+str(i)))
....:     for j in range(q):
....:         x_i_j.append(var('x_'+str(i)+'_'+str(j)))
....:         
sage: P = PolynomialRing(k,names=x_i)
sage: R = PolynomialRing(k,names=x_i_j)
sage: S = PolynomialRing(R,'t')
sage: subsvar = [sum((t^i*R.gen(i+q*j) for i in range(q))) for j in range(nvars)]
```

Usage:

```
sage: p = P.random_element(degree=2)
sage: p
(t)*x_0^2 + (t + 1)*x_1^2 + (t + 1)*x_0 + (t + 1)*x_1
sage: pp = S(str(p(subsvar)))
sage: pp.coefficients()
[x_0_1^2 + x_1_0^2 + x_0_0 + x_0_1 + x_1_0 + x_1_1, x_0_0^2 + x_1_0^2 + x_1_1^2 + x_0_0 + x_1_0]
```

Note the trick to transform a polynomial in the ring `R` into one in the ring `S`: make it a string and make `S` read the string.

To illustrate using your example:

```
sage: p = P('x_0 * x_1')
sage: p
x_0*x_1
sage: pp = p(subsvar)
sage: pp
x_0_0*x_1_0 + (t)*x_0_1*x_1_0 + (t)*x_0_0*x_1_1 + (t + 1)*x_0_1*x_1_1
sage: ppp = S(str(pp))
sage: ppp
(x_0_1*x_1_0 + x_0_0*x_1_1 + x_0_1*x_1_1)*t + x_0_0*x_1_0 + x_0_1*x_1_1
sage: ppp.coefficients()
[x_0_0*x_1_0 + x_0_1*x_1_1, x_0_1*x_1_0 + x_0_0*x_1_1 + x_0_1*x_1_1]
```

Here is the timing I obtain for the combined operation:

```
sage: timeit('S(str(p(subsvar))).coefficients()')
625 loops, best of 3: 1.31 ms per loop
```

For reference I am working with Sage 6.3.

```
sage: version()
'Sage Version 6.3, Release Date: 2014-08-10'
```